# GCE Instances inaccessible - connect: Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, centos, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, centos6

I booted my GCE instances this morning, and that 4/6 were completely inaccessible. All are in the same us-east1-d zone. SSH connections also weren't working, so I connected with serial console to one of the problematic instances.

When I try to ping any address, I get the following:
connect: Network is unreachable

Current ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0A:8E:00:0A  
          inet addr:10.142.0.10  Bcast:10.142.0.10  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:3955 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:650 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2231216 (2.1 MiB)  TX bytes:63705 (62.2 KiB)

eth0:cp1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0A:8E:00:0A  
          inet addr:10.240.0.73  Bcast:10.240.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:253775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:253775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:40106687 (38.2 MiB)  TX bytes:40106687 (38.2 MiB)
```

OS is Centos 6.10
Please advise, really have no idea what the issue is!

UPDATE

I was able to use the serial console to investigate the configured networks routes, somehow this route was missing:

```
GATEWAY0=10.142.0.1
NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
```

Added it to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 and the instances regained network access. Still trying to find the who/what/when/where/why this happened.

Comment: Hello Lordofdudes, I can see that you have posted solution of this issue in your question. Can you please post this solution as an answer so that the other community people looking at this post can be benefited from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same problem after a nightly yum update from CentOS 6.9 to 6.10 (around July 4).  It sounds like a bug was introduced in the dhcp packages where the default gateway route is missing after the update.

I actually came to the same conclusion you did by creating a route-eth0 file, but then I stumbled upon Google's issue tracker where they identify a slightly different solution until a permanent bug fix is released (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111154121). Their fix is to add a simple startup script (via the console) to your VM that defines the default gateway as the instance is booted:

```
#!/bin/bash
route add default gw [default_gateway_ip] eth0
```

In your case the default gateway ip is 10.142.0.1, so the full startup script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
route add default gw 10.142.0.1 eth0
```

This fix has been working reliably for me for a about a week now. I was unsure how the creation of a route-eth0 file would play out later on when a bug fix is released, so I reverted my changes to this solution instead. It sounds like RHEL has come up with a bug fix (https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2018:2163), but the CentOS repos haven't been updated yet last I checked.

Comment: Great job hunting down the bug trackers. I haven't implemented the Google recommended fixes yet, but manual routing solution is still working, so I'm going to do some more research before I change this in my prod env.